# Hide fields from ADAPT UI configuration^in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Depending on certain conditions, I have to hide a button in the header of my app. The coding in the controller is as follows:

```
if (condition === true) {
    this.byId(buttonId).setVisible(false); //works fine
} else {
    this.byId(buttonId).setVisible(true); //also works fine
}

//Code edit: Button is created on the go to check if Adapt UI can still find it. 
//However, it does not work still as expected. Button is visible to Adpat UI.

if (condition === true) {
var oButton = new sap.m.Button
     ({
       text : "Save",
       type :sap.m.ButtonType.Accept 
     });
oButton.placeAt('content'); 
 }
```

Moreover, the inital visiblilty of the button is set to *false* in the view definition.

```
<Button id="buttonId" text="Button1" press="onPress" visible="false"/>
```

In my app, this works as intended; button is hidden. However, if user goes to Adapt UI settings, it shows list of all the available buttons in the header. It also shows **button1**, even if it is not required in header atm.

**What I want to do?**
I want to hide button in adapt UI settings also. Button's visibility should be handled only via controller file.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you.

[image: ADAPT UI settings]

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the button with code at run-time when you want to provide user access to it - this way the button does not form part of the View at the outset.
I suspect the Adapt UI will allow access to anything in the Static View as it stands.

Comment: It does not work. Adapt UI can still find the button (I have updated code in question to show what I had tried).

Comment: But did you try before placing it (i.e. condition is false?) - it's unlikely to "see" something that does not yet exist (and I would remove when contextually no long relevant)